# Jsoup: вытащить текст из блока

Tags: java, jsoup, eclipse, android, синтаксический-анализ

Я только знакомлюсь с парсингом и пока немного не понимаю, есть код

```
    Document doc = null;
try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/").get();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String title = doc.title();
tvInfo.setText(title);
```

Как мне с помощью него вытащить текст не из title а из блока на сайте.

```
<dd class="value m_temp c">+20</dd>
```

Comment: пробовал вместо doc.title(); ставить doc.select("value m_temp c"); что то не получается. по нажатию кнопки программа вылетает с ошибкой. eclipse ошибок в коде не выдает

Comment: посмотри примеры на странице jsoup

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Почитайте хоть сайт, который парсите [Используем AsyncTask для загрузки изображений из сети](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/asynctask-imageinet.php)

Какой данный метод не работает? В последнем проекте использовал данную библиотику и все отлично работает.

Comment: Я не этот сайт парсить буду, это просто код который я нашел в интернете. Почитал про AsyncTask на android и на этом сайте, все равно не получается.

Comment: То что написано по этой ссылке и то дает понять в чем проблема. Просто вопросов с такой ошибкой уже миллион было. Как вы вообще что-то пишите, если даже по такой ошибке в стектрейсе не может найти решение?

Comment: Руками пишу, по кнопочкам так клац-клац и пишу. А про AsyncTask ни там ни там нормального мануала по использованию не нашел. java учу всего 3 дня и в синтаксисе не разобрался, а внятно что куда никто не может объяснить.

Comment: Что? Вы не нашли по первой ссылке нормального мануала? Тогда у меня для вас плохие новости

Answer (score 0):

```
doc.select("dd.value.m_temp.c").text();
```

И, судя по вышеприведённому куску кода, у вас вполне возможен NPE.

Comment: Все равно вылетает при нажатии на кнопку. Прочитал что данный метод не рабртает на андроид 4. Может поэтому ошибка?

Comment: может лучше дать стек ошибки?

Comment: Из LogCat http://vk.cc/1w49OI

Comment: В логе же ясно сказано, NetworkOnMainThreadException. Идём на http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html и читаем, что же это такое. А там ясно сказано: "The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread".

Answer (score 0):

Вот попробуй готовый пример. На вход передавай адрес

```
Dowload_i_Parsing_text task = new Dowload_i_Parsing_text();
task.execute("http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/");
```

вроде должно работать.

Вернётся `Document`, из которого можно всё получить.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

class Dowload_i_Parsing_text extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Подключение ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Document doInBackground(String... params) {
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup
                    .connect(params[0].toString())
                    .timeout(0)
                    .maxBodySize(0)
                    .get();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return doc;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Document doc) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        posle_potoka(doc); //обработка после потока
    }
```